# How to adjust a background image wihout affecting the container?

Tags: css

I am using the Electoral template from ThemeForest [here](http://n3rve.com/electoral/), this is the [original template](http://themeforest.net/item/electoral-political-nonprofit-html-template/8561461). I am trying to use CSS to fade out the edges of the blue image to the right, however the change is affecting the entire container. I've changed the background color  to reflect the undesired behavior at the first link.

What I want to do is be able to apply CSS instructions to **just** the image. This is the section that controls the container:

```
#hero .q-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 8%;
    background-image: url(../img/sam.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom 30% right 10%;
    background-size: 30%;
}
```

I tried using the following but it didn't work:

```
#hero .q-container img {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: We really need to see the HTML & CSS in a demo but it's not possible to affect the opacity of a background image with CSS.

Comment: I linked to them above. Can you at least provide instructions to use CSS on just the image to the right?

Comment: Links might get lost. A Short demo in a JSfiddle Demo would be more use. However, as I said, you cannot affect the opacity of, or 'fade',  background images with CSS.

Comment: I don't know what those are. Basically, I want to separate the two within the CSS but keep the layout looking the same. In order words, I want to be able to apply say a red background to just the image overlaying the other background. I believe this is an issue because the image is being called as a background in CSS, correct?

Comment: @Paulie_D --I forgot to mention you--